# RASA Failed to run custom action

Tags: python-3.x, rasa

action.py

```
import requests
import json
from rasa_core_sdk import Action, Tracker
class ActionJoke(Action):
    def name(self):
        return "action_joke"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        request = requests.get('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random').json() 
        joke = request['value']['joke'] 
        dispatcher.utter_message(joke) 
        return []
```

Input:

```
Your input ->  joke
```

Output:

2020-04-09 15:37:06 ERROR    rasa.core.actions.action  - Failed to run custom action 'action_joke'. 
Couldn't connect to the server at 'http://localhost:5055/webhook'. Is the server running?
     Error: Cannot connect to host localhost:5055 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 5055)]
    2020-04-09 15:37:06 ERROR    rasa.core.processor  - Encountered an exception while running action 'action_joke'. Bot will continue, but the actions events are lost. Please check the logs of
     your action server for more information.

Comment: nlu.md:

    ## intent:joke
    - Can you tell me a joke?
    - I would like to hear a joke
    - Tell me a joke
    - A joke please
    - Joke
    - joke

stories.md:

    ## story_joke_01
    * joke
      - action_joke

domain.yml

    intents:
    - greet
    - joke
    actions:
    - utter_greet
    - action_joke

Answer (score 2):

it looks like the Action Server is not running, hence it cannot be reached

```
rasa run actions
```

The log should tell it is running and which actions are being initialised.
You can then run rasa (or rasa shell) in a different terminal window.
Both components must be running.

Comment: One addition: you need to define `action_endpoint` in `endpoints.yml`, otherwise `rasa shell` will not look for the action server